Can't run django-admin in windows11
I was trying to start a new project in django and ran into this error.enter image description here i already created venv and installed django with venv activated.But even after successfull installlation of django i can't run django-admin command (it gives above error).
OS: Windows 11.
python: 3.13.0a6
Django: 5.0.6
i was expecting to create a new django project using django-admin startproject project_name

Python 3.13 is still in development and your Django 5.0.6 only supports Python 3.10 - 3.12.
To resolve your problem, use a supported Python version for your Django such as Python 3.12. See PyPi.
